# Add markers not working on google maps javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Ive been trying to get the place markers function to work but each time i click the map the marker won't show up. Ive tried adding console.log() statements inside the function and the program does go into the function when you click on the map and takes in the correct parameters, but the marker doesn't show up. If anyone could help id appreciate it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        var map,
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.8617, -4.2417);
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatLng,
                zoom: 15
            },
            marker;

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);

            placeMarker(myLatLng);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
            });
        }

        function placeMarker(location) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapDiv" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my own question actually. Declared the map variable twice, actually took me over an hour to notice that :(